# Adding an item to an array (state) and it is updating the previous record in the state

Tags: arrays, react-redux, state, store

My state has an array of objects, where every time the action `RECIPE_UPDATED` is triggered, a new object is added to the array. The very first item of the array is generated by the action `FIRST_RECIPE`. See the actions and reducers bellow.

The issue happens that every time the action `RECIPE_UPDATED` is called, it adds the new item to the array but it also changes the last item that was in the array before and so far I couldn't understand why it behaves as such.

These are the action creators:

```
export const getFirstRecipe = (recipe) => ({
  type: "FIRST_RECIPE",
  payload: recipe,
});

export const updateRecipe = (data) => ({
  type: "UPDATED_RECIPE",
  payload: data,
});
```

An these are the reducers:

```
const recipeHistoryReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FIRST_RECIPE":
      return [action.payload];

    case "UPDATED_RECIPE":
      return [...state, action.payload];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default recipeHistoryReducer;
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved.

It was not related to the reducers or actions at all. The whole issue was a mistake  where I was assigning the object with the values into a new variable without using the spread operator, so the whole thing was being changed at once.

Problem solved.
Jorge